# Switch switch vs ternary operator

Tags: swift, conditional-operator

In the sample code below: why does `flip1` compile but not `flip2`?

```
enum Coin {
   case heads
   case tails

    var flip1: Coin {
        switch self {
        case .heads: return .tails
        case .tails: return .heads
        }
    }

    var flip2: Coin {
        return self.heads ? .tails : .heads
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be `.heads` ? Just an observation

Comment: I meant after `:` the false evaluation. Also ternary expression require Boolean expressions

Comment: Indeed it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conditional operator takes a *boolean* expression as first operand:

```
var flip2: Coin {
    return self == .heads ? .tails : .heads
}
```